# css selector in angular directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives

Looking at the documentation for angular directives they list valid selectors.
https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

1. element-name: Select by element name
2. .class: Select by class name.
3. [attribute]: Select by attribute name.
4. [attribute=value]: Select by attribute name and value.
5. :not(sub_selector): Select only if the element does not match the sub_selector.
6. selector1, selector2: Select if either selector1 or selector2 matches.

But the only selectors that seems to work in a directive for me is 3 and 6.

Here is a stackblitz where I try to select `.test` css class in a directive and it doesn't work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-class-selector-in-directive

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the working example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-class-selector-in-directive-xqwriz

you need to register your directive into declaration in `app.module`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent, ComponentWithCssSelector, CssClassDirective } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ComponentWithCssSelector, CssClassDirective],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```